# How can i solve the following error with webpack,"Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' "

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

This is my webpack config

https://jsfiddle.net/oko5jp3L/

The problem started after i added this part

```
 node: {
    console: true,
    fs: true,
    net: true,
    tls: true
},
```

I added it because i was getting an error that fs is not defined. Do i have to install a node module, i'm new to webpack

Comment: Can you please try `fs:"empty"` ?

Comment: I added it because i was getting an error that fs is not defined. Is there any other way i can include fs?

Comment: Yeah.. Instead of adding it as `fs: true,` can you please try changing it as, `fs:"empty"` ?

Comment: I changed it to empty but im getting this error now
`Uncaught TypeError: _fs.readFileSync is not a function`

Comment: Are you using the `fs` module in your code anywhere? Something is referencing the `fs` (Filesystem) module somewhere.

Comment: In addition to @Dandy 's comment, Just in case if you are referencing the `fs` module, Can you please ensure that you are importing it in your code? like `require('fs')` for example?

Comment: One of the modules i'm using uses it internally, i requied fs in the file that file that uses that dependency, but i'm still getting that error

Comment: Any reason why you can't install `fs` as a module?

Comment: I installed it, but that didnt help

Comment: POst the error details as well